# I can't play any sound when screen is off

Tags: android, service, android-mediaplayer

I want to make an alarm sound on my phone, but when screen is off and my phone isn't connected to android studio terminal, there is no sound.

I'm executing the code from my `ForegroundService`, so it will have a high priority.
I tried `AlarmManager` and `MediaPlayer`.

This code makes sound every 50 cycles. When I lock my phone, sound disappears.

```java
lastNotifiedTime++;
                  if (lastNotifiedTime>50) {
                      mediaPlayer.start();
                      lastNotifiedTime=0;
                      SystemClock.sleep(1000);
                  }
```

my alarm randomly plays when screen is off once a few minutes.

How else can I play an alarm sound in a background?
Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: When your screen is off, the phone is likely to be asleep. That means that the uptimeMillis clock stops advancing, thus your `sleep` takes much longer than 1000ms.

Comment: How does it affect sounds?

Comment: Think about it: Your sound plays based on a timed interval. When your phone is asleep, that interval changes. There is no problem with the sounds.

Comment: When I delete all of my ```SystemClock.sleep``` and trigger an alarm with accelerometer, the same thing happens.

Comment: I really don't think accelerometers keep the device awake. So it's really the same problem. But you don't have to take my word for it: Just dump each accelerometer reading to logcat. You will have to unplug from USB to do the test, but when you plug back in, you can examine the logcat history and evaluate your accelerometer event delivery for any large gaps. See: [Non-wake up sensors](https://source.android.com/devices/sensors/suspend-mode.html#non-wake-up_sensors)

Comment: Yes, it's very good idea, but plugging in my phone to logcat keeps my smartphone awake, and then it works.

Comment: You may want to read my previous comment more carefully.

Comment: Ok, I didn't know that I can plug in and read log history. I will test it. Thanks.

Comment: Ok. After testing it looks like ```SystemClick.sleep``` doesn't work. Can I replace it with something else?

Comment: You've got some design decisions to make. Android has made this difficult b/c they don't want apps constantly draining the battery for trivial operations. But basically your options are: [WakeLock](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/wakelock), AlarmManager, WorkManager/JobScheduler. Sorry I can't go into more detail on these, I recommend you search for other answers.